# org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException table is not mapped

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I'm getting an error which looks like:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: DirectAddress is not mapped [select d from DirectAddress d where emailaddress=?]`

where query looks like

`Query query = session.createQuery("select d from DirectAddress d where emailaddress=?");`

and I have set an entity for javax

`@Entity
@Table(name = "user")`

Then I have tired that query:

`Query query = session.createQuery("select d from  " + DirectAddress.class.getName() + " d where emailaddress=?");`

without any luck.

Also project is not using `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it listed in the persistence.xml file?

Comment: It's not listed in the `persistence.xml` file but I have other entity which supports different class isn't there either and that's working. My code is based on that working code.

Answer (score 1):

To use an entity you've created, make sure it's marked as `@Entity` *using the javax library*. You'll also need to map it so hibernate knows it's supposed to link it to your database table. Please verify if your entity is mapped in your `applicationContext.xml` (for spring applications) or `persistence.xml` in common hibernate applications.

### Mapping your entities

> You can map your entities in many ways. The most common methods are:

#### Mapping it directly in `hibernate.cfg.xml`:

`<mapping class="your.packages.to.the.entity.class" />`

#### Setting it up in your spring applicationContext.xml`s hibernate configurations

For a working example, please refer to:
[How configure hibernate.cfg.xml to applicationContext.xml as dataSource?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197292/how-configure-hibernate-cfg-xml-to-applicationcontext-xml-as-datasource)

#### By Spring Injection

You mentioned not using hibernate.cfg.xml. Are you injecting hibernate`s settings via spring (in a non-web application)? If so, please refer to [Can we configure Hibernate Without hibernate.cfg.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335530/can-we-configure-hibernate-without-hibernate-cfg-xml)

If none of the solutions apply, please provide more details about your System (web, desktop, setting up hibernate programatically, etc) and i`ll edit with this answer with the most appropriate solution.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectAddress is not mapped [select d from DirectAddress d where emailaddress=?]
```

means hibernate did not find mapping for `DirectAddress` class. 
Check persistence.xml file for entity mapping or you can directly add this class while initializing/loading `Configuration`.